# how to put color to a textview with data in a listview?

Tags: android, android-listview

In my android application i have a list view with custom adapter which has two textviews. The first textview will always text in it, but the second textview will be empty in some cases. I am giving a background color to the second textview only where there is text. The problem i am facing here is once i scroll the listview, the color is assigned to the whole listview.

The data is being passed in the following manner to the adapter:

```
String time_array[] = new String[]{"12 AM","1 AM","2 AM","3 AM","4 AM","5 AM","6 AM","7 AM","8 AM","9 AM","10 AM","11 AM","12 PM","1 PM","2 PM","3 PM","4 PM","5 PM","6 PM","7 PM","8 PM","9 PM","10 PM","11 PM"};

    String item_array[] = new String[]{"item1","item1","item1","","","","item1","item1","item1","","","","item1","item1","item1","item1","","","","","item1","item1","item1",""};   



    for(int i=0;i<time_array.length;i++)
    {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("Time", time_array[i]);
        map.put("Item", item_array[i]);

        appointment_aaray.add(map);

    }
```

Below is the code that i am using for listview and coloring the second textview :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        viewHolder=new ViewHolder();//
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.appointment_timings_row, null);
        viewHolder.txt_time = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_time);
        viewHolder.txt_item = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_item);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }
    else
    {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map = data.get(position);        
    viewHolder.txt_time.setText(map.get("Time"));
    viewHolder.txt_item.setText(map.get("Item"));

    if (position % 2 == 1) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));  
    } else {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FEF8F8"));  
    }

    if(map.get("Item").equals(""))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        viewHolder.txt_item.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.item_text_color));

    }

    return convertView;

}
```

Can anybody help me with what i am missing here ?? 
Thank you in Adavance !

Comment: Try to set color of textview not view.

Comment: @shivani, check with declaring your ViewHolder locally and not globally.

Comment: @Thirumalvalavan the one which i am assigning to the textview only..`viewHolder.txt_item.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.item_text_color));` through this line

Comment: @SumighoshCharuvil the view color is the one which is for alternate rows in the listview. That is required.But the color assigned through this line `viewHolder.txt_item.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R‌​.color.item_text_color));` also is assigned to all the textviews even after putting the if else condition.

Comment: then you can do something like this. if(map.get("Item").equals(""))
    { 
      viewHolder.txt_item.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_when_no_text));
    } 
    else 
    { 
        viewHolder.txt_item.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.item_text_color));
 
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List view will create rows for the first visible rows later the same rows will be reused.So set the default color in the `if` condition

```
 if(map.get("Item").equals(""))
    {
       viewHolder.txt_item.setBackgroundColor(default_color);
    }
    else
    {
       viewHolder.txt_item.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.item_text_color));

    }
```